Solving a differential equation with a singularity
I am interested in solving the differential equation,
$$ y'(x) = -Ae^{-3y} $$
subject to the condition that $y(0) = 0$. This has an analytic solution,
$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{3}\ln(1 - 3A x)
$$
but I am interested in being able to push the numerical method as far as possible, so that I can apply the methodology to a more general problem. Below is the relevant code.
Clear["Global`*"]

prec = 100;

A = 5;

x0 = 0; xf = 2; y0 = 0;

diffeq = {y'[x] == -A*Exp[-3*y[x]], y[x0] == y0};

sol = NDSolve[diffeq, {y}, {x, x0, xf}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, PrecisionGoal -> prec/2, 
   WorkingPrecision -> prec, MaxSteps -> 50000];

For the code above, Mathematica quits when $x\sim 1.33$ which corresponds to $y\sim - 73$ or $e^{y}\sim 3.6\times 10^{-2}$.
I am looking for a method to push the numerical method to extend past its current limit, so that I can get as close as possible to $e^{y}\to 0$. I have tried increasing the precision, but with diminishing returns. Thanks in advance.

Out of curiosity, why are you interested in a numerical solution when you can have an analytic one?

A differential equation of the above form appears in a coupled system of equations in a more general problem I am considering. I am hoping that by solving the simpler problem numerically, I will be able to tackle the more advanced problem.

If you double the working precision, you'll double the value of $y$ at which integration stops, more or less, in a logarithmic singularity. That's basically the rate at which you can expect improvement, I think. Method -> "Extrapolation" usually does a bit better than "StiffnessSwitching" in my trials.

Singularity is at $x=1/(3A)=1/15$ in your case. It is not clear how do you get $x=1.33$.

I think the OP's desire to integrate much closer to the singularity, at least closer than what is shown below, is probably misplaced.  It is hard to be sure without the $Y$ question of this $XY$ problem.  It could be that the actual system is somewhat trickier than the MWE provided.  I think that whatever numerical analysis of the singularity is to be carried out, the solutions below would be sufficient.  Again, without knowing what analysis, I cannot be sure.
Two things principally determine how close to the singularity the integration can get, the minimum step size and the error estimate. The minimum step size is determined by the working precision as well as the integration method (I assume). At each step a method usually makes several function evaluations at distinct values of $x$ along the step. I assume that if these values are not distinct, the method become unreliable. If a step size is too small in this way, NDSolve[] stops the integration and issues an NDSolve::ndsz message. When the error estimate for a step is too great, the step is rejected and shortened. So it is likely that the integration will stop short of the singularity by a few steps or more at the last step size. I don't see a way around this. How big the value of $y$ will get depends on the singularity. For a logarithmic singularity like the example at hand, $|y| \sim C \log|x-x_0|$, which grows very slowly and is limited by the precision epsilon near $x_0$ if $x_0\ne0$. As I said in a comment, it is proportional to the number of digits in the working precision.
Even if you invert the problem, which may not be easy in the OP's indicated actual use-case of a system of ODE's, you cannot escape the precision problem because, while it is easy to step $y$ as far as desired, keeping the value of $x$ from oscillating around the value of the singular point.
Generate and memoize some solutions and solution data. Since we know the analytic solution, we can compare. The estimate "y-best" is the analytic value y would be if the solution were one minimal step away from the singularity, assuming the function evaluations are evenly spaced. (Neither is this true for all methods, nor is it important that it is not true; it is good enough for an approximation.)
orderMonitor[t_, method_NDSolve`Extrapolation] :=
  Sow[{t, method["DifferenceOrder"]}];
ysol // ClearAll;
mem : ysol[pg_, wp_] := mem = Module[{sol, orderdata},
    {sol, {orderdata}} = Reap@Quiet[
       NDSolveValue[diffeq, y, {x, x0, xf}, Method -> "Extrapolation",
         PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
        "MethodMonitor" :> orderMonitor[x, NDSolve`Self]], 
       NDSolveValue::ndsz];
    ysol[pg, wp, "order"] = orderdata;
    sol
    ];

Do[ysol[32, wp], {wp, 50, 500, 50}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {59.4028, Null}  *)

Do[ysol[25, wp], {wp, 50, 500, 50}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {35.3253, Null}  *)

PrecisionGoal mainly affects the time it takes.
Block[{
   pg = 25,   (* PrecisionGoal for this run (change as desired) *)
   xlast,     (* x closest to sing *)
   ylast,     (* y for xlast *)
   lastorder, (* integration order for last step *)
   step,      (* last step size *)
   },
 Labeled[
  TableForm[
   Table[
    xlast = ysol[pg, wp]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
    ylast = ysol[pg, wp]["ValuesOnGrid"] // Last;
    lastorder = ysol[pg, wp, "order"][[-1, 2]]; 
    step = First[Differences@ysol[pg, wp]["Grid"][[-2 ;;]]]; 
    {wp,
     Log[(3 a) lastorder*dx ]/3 /. dx -> xlast/10^wp // N[#, 6] &,
     ylast // N[#, 6] &,
     Log[(3 a) dx]/3 /. dx -> step // N[#, 6] &, (* est. y one step away *)
     1./(3 a) Exp[3 ylast]/step,   (* #steps from sing *)
     xlast - 1/(3 a) // N     (* error with exact sing *)
     }
    , {wp, 50, 500, 50}]
   , TableHeadings -> {None, {"wp", "y-best", "y-actual", 
      "y-one-step", "steps to go", 
      TraditionalForm[HoldForm@error[Subscript[x, "sing"]]]}}],
  PrecisionGoal -> pg, Top]
 ]



In some ways the data for PrecisionGoal -> 25 looks better: The distance (in steps, based on the value of $y$) to the singularity is estimated to be smaller and the terminal value of $y$ is greater in magnitude. On the other hand, the stopping value for x is much closer to the true singular point for PrecisionGoal -> 32. Neither are particularly close, and they correlate with the precision goal, not the working precision.  I'm cautious about whether these are a general trends or features of "nice" systems only.  But it should be assumed that the solutions are more accurate for higher precision goals, and therefore, their data are more reliable.
Note on the code for NDSolve:
My presentation has treated PrecisionGoal and WorkingPrecision as completely independent variables. I don't think this is strictly true. An insufficient precision goal sometimes leads to Overflow[] (for instance, 16 for working precision 100). This dependence can change with the method as well.

You might avoid  these numerical problems if you solve the inverse problem
X = NDSolveValue[{x'[y] == 1/(-A*Exp[-3*y ]), x[y0] == x0},x , {y, 0, 3} ];
ParametricPlot[{X[y], y}, {y, 0, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1,AxesLabel -> {x, y}]


